# Excel Target Entire Row using Text Content found in Cell

Tags: excel, vba

is there a way to target and show an entire row using text content found in a cell?

the screenshot below shows a sample questionnaire that users will have to answer, a ticked checkbox means 'yes' and a non-ticked checkbox means 'no'.

[image]

after answering, a requirement spreadsheet will generate the requirements needed by hiding "not needed requirements". below is a screenshot of the generated requirements spreadsheet.

[image]

below is a screenshot of the requirement matrix.

[image]

since the requirements in the requirement matrix can be altered (add/remove requirements, which will affect the row number.) the change in row number will affect the requirements being shown, the generated requirements spreadsheet is "hard-coded", meaning, my macros logic is "if question 1 checkbox is ticked, show row 2", so on and so forth.

hence, i am thinking of whether if it is possible to reference an entire row using text content found in a cell in the row itself. i apologise if i am unclear here, i will try to explain again if it is confusing. TIA

Edit: Markdown Tables generator, for example, i have the following table with the following response. question 1 is connected to requirement 1, question 2 is connected to requirement 2, question 3 is connected to requirement 3.

| Question Number | Response (Yes/No) |
| --- | --- |
| Question 1 | Yes |
| Question 2 | No |
| Question 3 | Yes |

this is yield me the following table due to the above response.

| Requirement Number | Description |
| --- | --- |
| General Requirement | Section Header |
| Requirement 1 | A |
| Security Requirement | Section Header |
| Requirement 3 | C |

as you can see, requirement 2 is hidden as the response for question 2 is 'No'. now, the requirement spreadsheet is constantly being updated, meaning, the row number of the requirement can be changed. for example, currently 'Requirement 3' is row number 7 (keep in mind that the Section Header and Requirement 2 is hidden), however, if a new update comes and a new row is being inserted into 'General Requirement', the row number for 'Requirement 3' will be changed, therefore hiding and unhiding a wrong row.

p.s. i am currently using row number to reference the entire row, hence, i am trying to figure out a way to reference an entire row using the description instead, since each description is unique.

Comment: Please show us your sample data as data (not as screenshots) by using [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) (read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16578424) for an explanation) - it is easier to help you then. Question: how are "Questions" (sheet Attributes) and "Requirements" related?

Comment: @Ike hi, i hope the recent edit gives an idea of how i want the excel macros to be like